# getting list index out of range from python code

Tags: python, sql

I am trying to build an SQL WHERE clause dynamically from a list of Columns and a list of Values. To do so, I have started with the code below:

```
sql_cols = ['description', 'height', 'weight', 'class' ]

sql_vals = [ 1, 2, 3, 4 ]

sql_test = " and".join( " f = :{}".format(x) for x in sql_vals )

print sql_test
```

This gives me the following results:

```
root@scar$ python testme.py
 f = :1 and f = :2 and f = :3 and f = :4
```

But what I am trying to get is something like this:

```
 `DESCRIPTION = :1 and HEIGHT = :2 and WEIGHT = :3 and CLASS = :4`
```

How can this be done?

EDIT:
changed code to:

sql_test = " and".join( sql_cols[x - 1] + "= :{}".format(x) for x in sql_vals )

and all worked

Comment: list iterator starts with 0, not 1, so first element is sql_cols[0]. plus, if you want to use cols instead of "f" you should format that one too, you're not changing that in any way

Comment: Duh!! - I must be out to lunch ... Thanks man!

Answer (score 2):

you can use this instead:

```
sql_cols = ['description', 'height', 'weight', 'class' ]

sql_vals = [ 1, 2, 3, 4 ]

sql_test = " and ".join("{} = :{}".format(*x) for x in  zip(sql_cols,sql_vals) )

print (sql_test)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
sql_test = " and ".join("{} = :{}".format(x[0].upper(), x[1]) for x in zip(sql_cols,sql_vals) )
```